# Add CC in PHP Mailer not working

Tags: php

Im trying to send on email to user using AddAddress and another three emails to admin and so on by CC .
I can send out email using AddAdress() But not using Add CC.
 Below is my code.

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "mail.test.com.my"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "enquiry@test.com.my";
$mail->AddAddress($email);

$mail->Subject  = "Colourful email";
$mail->Body     =$message;
/*$mail->WordWrap = 50;*/
$mail->AddCC    =($email_1);
$mail->AddCC    =($email_2);
$mail->AddCC    =($email_3);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Kindly check your email for the confirmation of your rental.Thank you.';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You dont need to `=` in this

```
$mail->AddCC($email_1);
```

Comment: You've gotta love the consistency where you DO need = for some things and don't need = for others.  And I get the difference between them, but it is still confusing.

Answer (score 13):

Try with this additional parameter

```
$mail->AddCC('person1@domain.com', 'Person One');
$mail->AddCC('person2@domain.com', 'Person Two');
```

Comment: The second parameter is Name parameter

Answer (score -1):

Just a typo here. The method is `addCC(string  $address, string  $name = '') : boolean` with a lower case 'a'

Comment: Class names as well as function/method names are case-insensitive.